# inputFilter not working with empty arrays (ZF2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Im receiving an object called *product* with an array inside called *tags*.

On my product model, tags looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
public $tags = array();
```

And my inputFilter is set to:

```
$this->get('tags')->setAllowEmpty(true)->setContinueIfEmpty(true)->setRequired(false);
$this->get('tags')->getValidatorChain()->attach(
    new Type('array')
);
```

Each time I receive the object with data inside the tags array everything goes ok, but as soon as I get an empty tags array i got:

```
array(1) {
  ["tags"] => array(1) {
    ["isEmpty"] => string(36) "Value is required and can't be empty"
  }
}

======================================================================
   The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
```

I think my filter is set ok, but regardless i still get an exception when i tried to save that object because the filter is asking for data.

EDIT: Here's a link to what I think is the actual bug: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that your 'tags' input is a \Zend\InputFilter\Input object instead of a \Zend\InputFilter\ArrayInput. This class ensure that the data given to the filter is an array, so you don't need a validator.

The following code returns true in ZF 2.2.5:

```
$filter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
$filter->add(new \Zend\InputFilter\ArrayInput('tags'));
$filter->get('tags')->setAllowEmpty(true)->setContinueIfEmpty(true)->setRequired(false);

$filter->setData(['tags' => []]);
$filter->isValid(); // returns true
```